# rosinstall not working after ROS package upgrade

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of this AM, I updated all the deb packages on my 16.04 machine, and now wstools 0.1.16 does not work.  0.1.12 still does.  With 0.1.16, I get this when I run rosws:

```
$ rosws up
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rosws", line 52, in <module>
    import rosinstall.rosws_cli
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosinstall/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    import wstool.helpers
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wstool/helpers.py", line 37, in <module>
    from wstool.config_elements import SetupConfigElement
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wstool/config_elements.py", line 43, in <module>
    from wstool.config_yaml import PathSpec
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wstool/config_yaml.py", line 37, in <module>
    import wstool.config
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wstool/config.py", line 35, in <module>
    from wstool.config_elements import AVCSConfigElement, OtherConfigElement, SetupConfigElement
ImportError: cannot import name AVCSConfigElement
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279585/rosinstall-not-working-after-ros-package-upgrade/) by [pbeeson](https://answers.ros.org/users/695/pbeeson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 276 on 2018-01-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-01-11**:
I'm looking into it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-11**:
Just an observation: `rosws` was (is?) specifically meant to manage `rosbuild` workspaces. It's replacement is `wstool`. A further evolution (which removes even more assumptions about the tools being used with/for ROS, is [vcstool](https://github.com/dirk-thomas/vcstool).

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-01-11**:
@pbeeson, can you answer this with a link to the issue you opened. Please try to keep bug reports to one location. :+1:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Debugged and resolved in: https://github.com/vcstools/wstool/issues/116

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0